# Update Entity from ViewModel in MVC using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper

I have a `Supplier.cs` Entity and its ViewModel `SupplierVm.cs`. I am attempting to update an existing Supplier, but I am getting the Yellow Screen of Death (YSOD) with the error message:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

I **think** I know why it is happening, but I'm **not sure how to fix it**. Here's a [screencast](http://www.screencast.com/t/pjoUdUKYqY3n) of what is happening. I think the reason I'm getting the error is because that relationship is lost when AutoMapper does *its thing*.

**CODE**

Here are the **Entities** that I think are relevant:

```cs
public abstract class Business : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TaxNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; } = new List<Address>();
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } = new List<Contact>();
}

public class Supplier : Business
{
    public virtual ICollection<PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrders { get; set; }
}

public class Address : IEntity
{
    public Address()
    {
        CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public int BusinessId { get; set; }
    public virtual Business Business { get; set; }
    
}

public class Contact : IEntity
{
    public Contact()
    {
        CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    public int BusinessId { get; set; }
    public virtual Business Business { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my **ViewModel**:

```cs
public class SupplierVm
{
    public SupplierVm()
    {
        Addresses = new List<AddressVm>();
        Contacts = new List<ContactVm>();
        PurchaseOrders = new List<PurchaseOrderVm>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [Display(Name = "Tax Number")]
    public string TaxNumber { get; set; }
    
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    
    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
      
    public IList<AddressVm> Addresses { get; set; }
    public IList<ContactVm> Contacts { get; set; }
    public IList<PurchaseOrderVm> PurchaseOrders { get; set; }

    public string ButtonText => Id != 0 ? "Update Supplier" : "Add Supplier";
}
```

My **AutoMapper mapping configuration** is like this:

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<Supplier, SupplierVm>();

cfg.CreateMap<SupplierVm, Supplier>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Addresses, o => o.UseDestinationValue())
    .ForMember(d => d.Contacts, o => o.UseDestinationValue());
      
cfg.CreateMap<Contact, ContactVm>();
cfg.CreateMap<ContactVm, Contact>()
    .Ignore(c => c.Business)
    .Ignore(c => c.CreatedOn);
      
cfg.CreateMap<Address, AddressVm>();

cfg.CreateMap<AddressVm, Address>()
    .Ignore(a => a.Business)
    .Ignore(a => a.CreatedOn);
```

Finally, here's my **SupplierController** Edit Method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(SupplierVm supplier)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
        return View(supplier);

    _supplierService.UpdateSupplier(supplier);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And here's the `UpdateSupplier` Method on the `SupplierService.cs`:

```cs
public void UpdateSupplier(SupplierVm supplier)
{
    var updatedSupplier = _supplierRepository.Find(supplier.Id);
    Mapper.Map(supplier, updatedSupplier); // I lose navigational property here
    
    _supplierRepository.Update(updatedSupplier);
    _supplierRepository.Save();
}
```

I've done a load of reading and according to [this blog post](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2013/11/updating--entities-with-automapper.aspx), what I have should work! I've also read [stuff like this](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code) but I thought I'd check with readers before ditching AutoMapper for Updating Entities.

Comment: You should check what updatedSupplied has in it, does it have child properties. Error makes it very your child items are becoming null and hence foreign key error.

Comment: At what stage? do you mean after AutoMapper does its thing or before it? If you mean before it, all looks OK, everything is as it should be as far as I can tell.

Comment: Okay which suggests mapping is not setting the navigation property. Essentially   .ForMember(d => d.Addresses, o => o.UseDestinationValue()) isn't working.You might need to explicitly create a mapping configuration.

Comment: Take a look at the second answer on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11872051/5481661).  Deals with mapping and preserving nested classes like you are doing

Comment: Thanks @big_water, what does `.ForMember(dest => dest.ID, opt => { opt.UseDestinationValue(); opt.Ignore(); });` do? It is like telling it to use the DestinationValue but at the same time to ignore it which doesn't make sense to me!

Comment: @Ciwan, It ignores the ID key because it might be null.  If you are using the destination values in your mapping, there won't be any updates to the navigation properties. So ignoring it may be the solution since it sounds like the navigation properties may have null values.

Comment: @Ciwan, you do have mappings defined for your Address and Contact classes to their respective view models, right?

Comment: @big_water, yep I've just added those to the question

Comment: @Ciwan, it looks like you might have a circular reference which is causing AutoMapper to fault out.  Can you post your Address and Contact classes?

Comment: @big_water, no problem. I've added those too

Comment: @Ciwan, you have a circular reference from business to addresses, and then back from the address model to the business.  Same with contact. Try commenting out this `public virtual Business Business { get; set; }` from both your Address and Contact class and running it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132347/discussion-between-ciwan-and-big-water).

Comment: @Ciwan I suspect AutoMapper might be acting up on the `ICollection <-> IList` conversion. Can you update your Entity model so that `Addresses` and `Contacts` are `ILists`? Or otherwise examine this question, which suggests creating a mapping between the two types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479208/automapper-auto-map-collection-property-for-a-dto-object

Comment: Hi .. I think the problem of loosing navigation property is that you do the Map outside the repository .. so it can't retrive dinamyccaly (lazyloading) your navigation property .. if you want to do it outside repo .. you need to eagder loading the related entities (navigation) that you want to be mapped on your ViewModel

Comment: Do you want to update `supplier` properties only, or also properties in addresses, etc.?

Comment: A supplier has a list of addresses and contacts. But only one address and one contact can be active (`IsDeleted == false`) at any one time. When I edit a Supplier, I am editing the Supplier and his active Address and Contact. So I want all 3 entities updated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### The cause

The line ...

```
Mapper.Map(supplier, updatedSupplier);
```

... does a lot more than meets the eye.

1. During the mapping operation, `updatedSupplier` loads its collections (`Addresses`, etc) lazily because AutoMapper (AM) accesses them. You can verify this by monitoring SQL statements.
2. AM *replaces* these loaded collections by the collections it maps from the view model. This happens despite the `UseDestinationValue` setting. (Personally, I think this setting is incomprehensible.)

This replacement has some unexpected consequences:

3. It leaves the original items in the collections attached to the context, but no longer in scope of the method you're in. The items are still in the `Local` collections (like `context.Addresses.Local`) but now deprived of their parent, because EF has executed *relationship fixup*. Their state is `Modified`.
4. It attaches the items from the view model to the context in an `Added` state. After all, they're new to the context. If at this point you'd expect 1 `Address` in `context.Addresses.Local`, you'd see 2. But you only see the added items in the debugger.

It's these parent-less 'Modified` items that cause the exception. And if it didn't, the next surprise would have been that you add new items to the database while you only expected updates.

#### OK, now what?

So how do you fix this?

**A.** I tried to replay your scenario as closely as possible. For me, one possible fix consisted of two modifications:

1. Disable lazy loading. I don't know how you would arrange this with your repositories, but somewhere there should be a line like

   ```
   context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   ```

   Doing this, you'll only have the `Added` items, not the hidden `Modified` items.
2. Mark the `Added` items as `Modified`. Again, "somewhere", put lines like

   ```
   foreach (var addr in updatedSupplier.Addresses)
   {
       context.Entry(addr).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
   }
   ```

   ... and so on.

**B.** Another option is to map the view model to new entity objects ...

```
  var updatedSupplier = Mapper.Map<Supplier>(supplier);
```

... and mark it, and all of its children, as `Modified`. This is quite "expensive" in terms of updates though, see the next point.

**C.** A better fix in my opinion is to take AM out of the equation completely and *paint the state* manually. I'm always wary of using AM for complex mapping scenarios. First, because the mapping itself is defined a long way away from the code where it's used, making code difficult to inspect. But mainly because it brings its own ways of doing things. It's not always clear how it interacts with other delicate operations --like change tracking.

Painting the state is a painstaking procedure. The basis could be a statement like ...

```
context.Entry(updatedSupplier).CurrentValues.SetValues(supplier);
```

... which copies `supplier`'s scalar properties to `updatedSupplier` if their names match. Or you could use AM (after all) to map individual view models to their entity counterparts, but ignoring the navigation properties.

Option C gives you fine-grained control over what gets updated, as you originally intended, instead of the sweeping update of option B. When in doubt, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30824229/861716) may help you decide which option to use.

Comment: Thanks Gert, this was a beautiful answer!

Comment: Hi @Gert, I see in the question, the op pass ViewModel to service layer? Is that good design?

Comment: @Willy Most of the times, a view model is just a DTO. For me it's OK to pass DTOs to and from a service layer--actually that's what they're for. If a view model is really a view model (containing INotifyPropertyChanged and/or the whole shebang of directing the view), no, I'd not do it, because it probably bleeds UI library dependencies into the service layer.

Answer (score 1):

I searched all stackoverflow answers and google searches. Finally i just added 'db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;' line and it worked perfectly for me.

> ```
>  var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserMessage>(@"{.....}");
>         using (var db = new OracleDbContex())
>         {
>             db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
>             var msguser = Mapper.Map<BAPUSER>(message);
>             var dbuser = db.BAPUSER.FirstOrDefault(w => w.BAPUSERID == 1111);
>             Mapper.Map(msguser, dbuser);
>             //  db.Entry(userx).State = EntityState.Modified;
>
>             db.SaveChanges();
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this issue many times and is normally this:

The FK Id on the parent reference doesn't match the PK on that FK entity.  i.e. If you have an Order table and a OrderStatus table. When you load both into entities, Order has OrderStatusId = 1 and the OrderStatus.Id = 1.  If you change OrderStatusId = 2 but do not update OrderStatus.Id to 2, then you'll get this error.  To fix it, you either need to load the Id of 2 and update the reference entity or just set the OrderStatus reference entity on Order to null before saving.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is going to fit your requirement but I would suggest following.

From your code it surely looks like you are loosing relationship during mapping somewhere.

To me it looks like that as part of UpdateSupplier operation you are not actually updating any of the child details of the supplier.

If that is the case I would suggest to updadate only changed properties from the SupplierVm to the domain Supplier class. You can write a separate method where you will assign property values from SupplierVm to the Supplier object (This should change only non-child properties such as Name, Description, Website, Phone etc.).

And then perform db Update. This will save you from possible messup of the tracked entities.

If you are changing the child entities of supplier, I would suggest to update them independent of suppliers because retrieving an entire object graph from database would require lot of queries to be executed and updating it will also execute unnecessary update queries on database.

Updating entities independently would save lot of db operations and would add to the performance of the application.

You can still use the retrieval of entire object graph if you have to display all the details about the supplier in one screen. For updates I would not recommend update of entire object graph.

I hope this would help resolving your issue.